# Filter only numbers (0-9) in output in Windows cmd

Tags: cmd, numbers, output

I have a text, for example:

cd123aaq54
and I'd like to separate only numbers in another file, so I could have

12354
in the output.

I have been trying a lot of commands like

Get-Content text.txt | Select-String  -Pattern '[0-9]'
In linux it's much easier, just

grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*' text >numbers

I know that in Powershell is 
@(Get-Content text.txt) -replace '\D',''
But it is too slow (I want it in a loop)
How can I do in in classic cmd?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "input=cd123aaq54"
CALL :numsonly result "%input%"
ECHO %input% --^> %result%
SET "input=cd5z43a q21p"
CALL :numsonly result "%input%"
ECHO %input% --^> %result%
GOTO :EOF

:numsonly
setlocal
SET "$1="
SET "$2=%~2"
:numsloop
IF "%$2:~0,1%" geq "0" IF "%$2:~0,1%" leq "9" SET "$1=%$1%%$2:~0,1%"
SET "$2=%$2:~1%"
IF DEFINED $2 GOTO numsloop

endlocal&SET "%1=%$1%"
GOTO :eof
```

The `:numsonly` subroutine could be put into a separate batch file if desired.

Comment: What ´d like to do is a script that takes a doc.txt and create a new one with only nombers. Like:
doc.txt>onlynumbers.txt


Like grep -o '[0-9][0-9]*' text >numbers in linux